# Does too many Linq DataContexts slow down loading time?

Tags: c#, sql, performance, linq, azure

my data access Layer uses syntax something like the following:

```
public static List<MyTableInstance> dataBaseAccessMethod(int someValue)
{
    using(myCustomDataContext db = new myCustomDataContext())
    {
        return (from x in db.MyTable where x.Param = someValue select x).ToList();
    }
}
```

The question is: if a page is accessing 20 data access methods like the one above, and hence creating 20 myCustomDataContext objects, is this reducing loading times of my page due to a round-trip being introduced for each myCustomDataContext. i.e) In theory would reducing the number of dataContext objects for each page have any significant impact on the loading time of the web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority of time is consumed by round-trips to database. You need to combine queries to lower the number of roundtrips. It is not about the number of dataContext objects, even with single dataContext object you can do a LOT of roundrips to database.